# Any idea what this fish is?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

Bought this Fish at the pet shop today. Forgot it's name. 
That pink fish
[image]

Comment: It might be easier to go back to the pet shop...

Answer (score 1):

Your fish in question is a [zebra danio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebrafish) [GloFish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GloFish); they're genetically engineered to have flourescent coloration. The giveaways for me were the shape of the body (minnow shaped, with zebrafish belonging to the minnow family), its size (small), and the striped pattern running along the body, parallel to the lateral line. Since the fish in your picture is in motion, it's a bit difficult to see, but it's definitely there (can be seen closer to the head).

[image: zebra danio]

And here's another image, where the coloration is closer to what you have. (IMO, the previous image has a strong contrast, especially with the black background)

[image: zebra danios with bent spine]

This zebrafish is suffering from a bent spine, which accounts for the misshapen body. ([source](http://www.wetwebmedia.com/fwsubwebindex/zebraddisf.htm))

---

Also, it seems that the fish in the background is a [black-skirt tetra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_tetra).

[image: black skirt tetra]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a Pink Dottyback.

[image]

<sup>[[Source:Blue Zoo Aquatics](https://www.bluezooaquatics.com/productDetail.asp?did=1&pid=2032&cid=21)]</sup>

Comment: Seems like your identification is correct. I suggest you add an image from google here instead of telling to double check it.

Comment: Also +1 since I had no idea who downvoted the answer.

Comment: @user33990 I have added the image for you, but please provide some description of the species that why you think it's correct.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please add some more details in your answer.

Comment: Are you sure? The top fin seems much longer, the shape of the tail is very different, the color of the eye is different. I'm fish biologist, but I have doubts.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's a saltwater fish. The tank in the picture, I'm 99.999% sure it's freshwater. Also, I agree with @RHA.